# Angular project structure for multiple customer projects

Tags: angular

We are facing a problem (re-)starting our software project, which I hope someone her can help with. I would like to describe our situation first.

We are developing a standard software which we deliver as is (with small configurations) to small and medium size customers. For our enterprise projects, we are using the same codebase but making changes to fit the needs of our enterprise customers, which exceed the possibilities we can and want to achieve via configuration. A huge part of the source code will be the same in all projects, so we don't want to maintain it multiple times.

We created an angular project and our initial idea was, that we can use that standard project and just extent and overwrite our components with changed once for our enterprise projects.
The problem we are facing now, is that angular selectors need to be unique in the whole project. And if we want to exchange a selector in a multi level component hierarchy, we would need to replicate the whole hierarchy for the enterprise projects. Which is exactly what we don't want to do.

Are there any best practices or recommendations how we can handle this situation? I would be very thankful for your help. I hope my explanation is clear so far. If I can clarify anything, just let me know.

Comment: Without knowing all the details I would say you need some defined interfaces and custom npm packets which are implementing these interfaces and which are interchangeable. I think it doesn't matter if these interfaces are just parts of a component or maybe the whole component. To speak in general things have to be decoupled.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Angular NX](https://nx.dev/) is going to help you. Basically it will allow you to have a monorepo and an architecture according to your needs. You can create multiple components and share them across apps with minimium effort, among other things like Directives or Interfaces.

What's better is that you'll need less time to develop and maintain it.

PS: I'm not related in any way to that project.